# sql table desgin

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

i faced an interview question yesterday regarding sql table design. 
  the question is if the table contains fields like firstName,lastName,Gender(only these fields not not any more)which one we can select as a primary key?

any hint will greatly appreciated 
Thank you

Comment: Um... none? Seeing as any of these fieds can be duplicated....

Comment: The right answer is surely none of those

Answer (score 3):

None of them will be unique within the table, so you need to make an extra primary key field that auto-increments so that it will be guaranteed never to be the same for two rows. Sounds like they got you with a trick question :)

Answer (score 1):

A `PRIMARY KEY` must be unique. So you must construct it from data which will not repeat.

Answer (score 0):

So primary key is a unique & not null value.

if the table contains fields like firstName,lastName,Gender(only these fields not not any more)which one we can select as a primary key.

there is you can not use above column as a primary key.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my 2 cents (these rules applies for every new table, for the beginner schema designers)

- the primary key should not be compound (that is, it should contain only 1 column)
- the primary key column should contain no meaningful data (it should be a number generated and assigned automatically to the new record)
- the  value of primary key should never change, and should not be null
- besides the primary key, you should have an other unique key, probably a compound key, using the meaningful data fields, just to make sure you do not have duplicate records (e.g. firstName,lastName,dateOfBirth)

Answer (score 0):

You can combine one field with another field that will give you a primary key (not very recommendable, but you can make this field plus a timestamp field your combined primary key).....

Comment: i gave the same answer, but he looked at me very strangely :-)